# Is HTML 5 mature enough to be used in production website?

Tags: html

I have a simple question, is HTML 5 mature enough to be used in production website ? Are moslty all browser compatible with this new technology nowdays ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what features you are going to use. Here is a compatibility chart for CSS3 and HTML5:

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/

Some features are probably safe to use without a fallback. Others may need a fallback. There are some libraries out there that attempt to pull non-supporting browsers up to a bit:

http://www.modernizr.com/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on which html5 technologies you want to use.  Different browsers support the varying html5 items to different degrees.  Here is a chart showing which browsers support which different parts of html5

http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/

you can probably google to find more specifics.

That said, if your target is to support all browsers under the sun, then you are going to have a lot of work to do to get your app to work perfectly on all browsers.  If you target, say, Chrome, FF, and Safari, your job will be easier, but even then some differences exist.  For example, FF does not support css3 animations, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, it's not ready. HTML5 is still a Working Draft. API still could change.

See this recent interview with Philippe Le Hégaret:

> The problem we're facing right now is there is already a lot of excitement for HTML5, but it's a little too early to deploy it because we're running into interoperability issues"

[Interview](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/w3c-hold-html5-in-websites-041)

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML5 is based off existing methods used widely, I would say that it's ready for production. Just know that not ALL browsers support it, but any modern day browser should. There are still many companies forcing their employees to use IE6 due to their applications not working with newer browser.

All mobile browsers, and any modern version of FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera will work.

I would test on as many browsers as possible before moving from development though.

Good luck!